# Problem with Enable/Disable a button on SALV Full Screen

Tags: abap, alv

Dear all I need your help on the below desperately.

I have created an ALV from SALV and I have copied a GUI Status `SALV_STANDARD` from a standard program. Firstly I added 2 buttons the POSTNEW & POSTDIFF and after a day I added the **SELECT** button.

Depending on the selection of the user I want to enable or disable the buttons according to the business requirements.

I have this code in a procedure:

```
  r_alv type reference CL_SALV_TABLE.
  if status_name is not initial and report_name is not initial.
    set pf-status status_name.
    r_alv->set_screen_status(
      pfstatus      =  status_name
      report        =  report_name
      set_functions = r_alv->c_functions_all ).
  endif.

  data: lit_functions_list type salv_t_ui_func,
        lwa_functions_list like line of lit_functions_list.

  r_functions = r_alv->get_functions( ).  "Get Toolbar functions
  lit_functions_list = r_functions->get_functions( ).

  if i_button_name is not initial.
** Now hide the BUTTON
    loop at lit_functions_list into lwa_functions_list.
      if lwa_functions_list-r_function->get_name( ) = i_button_name.
        lwa_functions_list-r_function->set_visible( i_button_visable ).
      endif.
    endloop.
  endif.
```

The variables `status_name`, `report_name`, `i_button_name` and `i_button_visable` are parameters of the procedure and I think that their names show what they are carrying.

The internal table **lit_functions_list** has 60 records and the last 2 have data for the first 2 buttons and this is the reason that I can enable/disable them.
But there is no record with my 3rd button **SELECT**. Instead there is a record with the button MYFUNCTION which I have already deleted.

Can someone tell me what to do in order to have the 3rd button available in the **lit_functions_list**?

Can someone tell me why this itab has so many garbages?

Thanks in advance
Elias

Comment: Did you activate the CUA interface (containing all GUI status & titles) after you have changed it?

Comment: What you call "**garbage**" is the list of all possible standard function codes. Note that you usually don't need to loop at this list to disable one function code (possibly a button), because you know its "name" (in fact its "function code"), it's easier to disable it with `r_alv->get_functions( )->set_function( name = 'ZZZ' boolean = abap_false ).` (where ZZZ is the function code)

Answer (score 2):

Even I had the same problem. After I ran the report BALVBUFDEL it solved the issue.
Newly created buttons now coming inside the function list ..

```
lit_functions_list = r_functions->get_functions( ).
```

Answer (score 0):

For Adding 3rd button in the lit_functions_list, You can use below code.

```
  r_functions->set_function( NAME = 'BUT3' BOOLEAN = 'X' ).
```

you can also use add_function to add new button.

```
try.
  r_functions->add_function(
    name     = 'BUT3'
    icon     = l_icon
    text     = l_text
    tooltip  = l_text
    position = if_salv_c_function_position=>right_of_salv_functions ).
  catch cx_salv_existing cx_salv_wrong_call.
endtry.
```

itab does not have garbage. It contains all the data related to status like menu bar, application tool bar and function keys.

Comment: Umar, I have created the button (function) 'SELECT' in GUI Status. I added your code but it does not work and have the following error in code:  ```abap  enable_function( name    = name
                           boolean = if_salv_c_bool_sap=>true ).   text   = text-001.
    l_name = name.
    raise exception type CX_SALV_METHOD_NOT_SUPPORTED
        exporting class  = 'CL_SALV_FUNCTIONS'
                  method = 'ENABLE_FUNCTION'
                  object = l_name
                  key    = text.  ```     TEXT-001=Only Possible in Grid View  NAME=SELECT .

Comment: ERROR: **Class CL_SALV_FUNCTIONS, method ENABLE_FUNCTION not supported for SELECT Only
Possible in Grid View**

Comment: My code is example only. You have to declare variables and method calls accordingly.

Comment: For more detail, You can see in Program SALV_DEMO_TABLE_FUNCTIONS.

Comment: The method `ADD_FUNCTION` cannot be used on a Full Screen ALV, because the buttons are statically defined in a GUI status (the one indicated via method `SET_SCREEN_STATUS`. Only the method `SET_FUNCTION` can be used to enable or disable a function code (a button in the context of this question).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer at least to my problem. Let me describe again what I did:
I copy the **GUI Status** from the standard program SALV_DEMO_TABLE_FUNCTIONS to my program through Tcode SE41. I added 2 buttons **POSTNEW** & **POSTDIF**. Until now all working perfect and I can Enable/Disable these 2 buttons.
Next day the business asked me to add a button **SELECT** with which the user can make editable the corresponding SELECT column of the itab in order to choose which record to be posted. And here started my problem where the itab with the functions didn't contain the last created button SELECT. What I did was, I created a button through the design process of the GUI Status but I could not get it through the below code:

```
lit_functions_list = r_functions->get_functions( ).
```

With your answers I found other problems in my code but still I could not get the new button in the above itab.
Finally, yesterday evening I remembered, what someone told me in the past. In old systems (like oursSAP ECC 6.0 R701 SP007) sometimes the ALV buffer stuck and we have to reset it. So I run the program **BALVBUFDEL** and vuala the button **SELECT** appeared in the itab and I can now Enable or Disable.
So keep in mind that sometimes the ALV buffer needs a reset.
Thanks all for your help.
Elias